# Two models are loaded in keras to test the network, but only the first model works. The later loaded one does not work properly

Tags: python, keras

---

I have trained two network models independently using keras. In the test phase, I need to use both of the trained models. However, there comes the problem. No matter how I change the statement order of the models, it is always only the first stated model works well while the models after the first model all don't work properly. And the layers' names of all the models are unique. Part of my codes:

```
input_shape = (tsz[0], tsz[1], 3)
s_input_shape = (s_tsz[0], s_tsz[1], 3)        
model_full = o2o_test(input_shape)
model = Model(inputs=model_full.input, outputs=model_full.get_layer('get_vgg16_output').output)
model.load_weights('./checkpoints/weights.0076-0.3648-0.1801-0.0507-0.0498-2.0425.hdf5', by_name=True)
s_model_full = o2o_test_s(input_shape, s_input_shape)
s_model = Model(inputs=s_model_full.input, outputs=s_model_full.get_layer('get_vgg16_output_s').output)
s_model.load_weights('./checkpoints_coarse_search/weights.0025-0.1547-0.0884-0.4746.hdf5', by_name=True)
```

### This problem stuck me for two days. Hope anyone can help me find out the reason.

Comment: Why does a model use only `input_shape` and the other uses `input_shape, s_input_shape`. What is the difference between the models? Is one supposed to contain the other?

Comment: Thanks for response. The models are independent of each other, no Interaction. The structure of the two model are different.  I only need to run the two models independently in one python script. I try to change the statement order of the models. Find that only the first stated one works well. And both the models work well if I just left oneself in the file

Comment: Is the code for `o2o_test` and `o2o_test_s` available?

Comment: The code is too long to be posted here. But I am sure that the two models are totally independent from each other and they are trained separately using two computers.

Comment: Well.... I can't see a problem in the code you posted, so I guess it may be in the definition. I do use lots of models simultaneously without a problem (but I don't use "load_weights").